# Sending messages from NodeJS server to Web client

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send messages from my server to a client, but can't quite get it to work (`onMessage` handler is never called).

In `chrome://gcm-internals/` tab whenever I run the server code I can see messages coming in. It means connection between the server and a browser is OK. The problem must be in the client-code.

[image]

**Here's general flow:**

- Client code (pseudo code) connects to `firebase`, obtains `token`,
  subscribes to `onMessage` event.
- Server code (pseudo code) connects to `firebase` sends `payload` to client using client's token

**Client code:**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
require('firebase/messaging')
import { serviceWorkerRegistration } from './worker.service'

const config = {
  apiKey: <...>,
  authDomain: <...>,
  databaseURL: <...>,
  projectId: <...>,
  storageBucket: <...>,
  messagingSenderId: <...>
}

const app = firebase.initializeApp(config)
const messaging = firebase.messaging()

messaging.useServiceWorker(serviceWorkerRegistration)

messaging.getToken()
  .then(token => console.log(token)
  .catch(error => console.log(error))

messaging.onMessage(function (payload) {
  console.log('Message received:', payload)
})
```

**Server code:**

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const config = require('./config')
const signature = require('./signature.json')

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(signature),
  databaseURL: config.databaseURL
})

const messaging = admin.messaging()

const token = <...>

const payload = {
  data: {
    text: "Hello from server"
  }
}

admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload)
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log('response:',response)
    console.log('response.results:',response.results)
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error sending message:", error)
  })
```

As I understood it from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive) this setup can handle incoming messages when app is in `foreground`, but for some reason it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: It turns out the problem was in that I needed to initialize app instance in the`service-worker`. I'll post updates a bit later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, to make notifications and messages work it's nessesary to initiate `messaging` in the `service worker` file.

**service-worker.js (snippet)**

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-app.js')
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-messaging.js')
firebase.initializeApp({ messagingSenderId: <...> })
const messaging = firebase.messaging()

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
  console.log(payload)
  const title = payload.data.title
  const options = {
    body: payload.data.title,
    icon: '/notification-icon-192.png'
  }
  return self.registration.showNotification(title, options)
})
```